# How to get a randomly generated path from a folder with images

Tags: python, path

So, I have a folder with a bunch of images.  Is there a way that I can randomly select one of them and return the path of the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os
import random
folder_directory = r"C:/Users/Andrew/Desktop/Beta-Testing/memes"
file_path = folder_directory[:-1] + "\\" + random.choice(os.listdir(folder_directory))
print('r"'+file_path+'"')
```

Gets this outout

```
r"C:/Users/Andrew/Desktop/Beta-Testing/memes\meme10.jpeg"
```

Comment: is there i can get it so that it outputs it like this? r"path for file"

Comment: i updated my code, @AndrewSaenger is that what you meant?

Comment: yea so it would print r"C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\Beta-Testing\memes/meme1.jpg" instead of just the file path

Comment: I updated it like you did and i get this r"C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\Beta-Testing\memesmeme10.jpg"

Comment: you want the last backslash facing the other way?

Comment: no its fine i just need to add a backslash in-between the memes and the meme.10jpg

Comment: @AndrewSaenger is this what u meant?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `glob.glob` and `random.choice`:

```
import glob
import random

file_path = random.choice(glob.glob("/path/to/folder/*"))
```

Comment: If your path includes backslashes, yes (e.g. `r"C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\Images"`).

Answer (score 0):

For this problem you will want the subprocess library (this runs commands on the shell and can record their output), and you want the random library. For starters you will want the output of the directory so something like this will get you the output in string format:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
pipe = Popen("put the command here i.e. the path plus the command", stdout=PIPE, shell = True)
text = pipe.communicate()[0]
print(text)
```

with the variable text you can parse it (this you are going to have to figure out on your own)and get all of the files into a list, from there:

```
import random
chosen_file = random.choice(list_of_files)
list_of_files.remove(chosen_file) #this is so that you dont have the same photo twice
```

then, bada-bing,bada-boom you should be able to randomly select photos in the directory, as a side note make sure you include the directory of the photos in the subprocess command unless you want to keep this python file in the same folder as them

Hope this helps, all the best

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import random

# get a list of all the files in the folder
file_list = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\images")

# get a random file from the list
random_file = random.choice(file_list)

# print the path of the random file
print(os.path.join(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\images", random_file))
```